# K-Fold Cross Validation Gives Strange Results When using full dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

So there's this dataset I've been using and I split it into Train and Test set(20% Test). So when I use K-fold cross validation on the training data with cv=10, it gives normal accuracy but when I use it on the entire dataset(Train+Test) it gives strange results in negative. There's even a -128 there. What is happening?

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,[0,2]].values
Y = data.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=tts(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=LinearRegression(),X=X_train,y=Y_train,cv=10)
accuracies_dataset= cross_val_score(estimator=LinearRegression(),X=X,y=Y,cv=10)
```

accuracies_dataset gives unusual negative values but accuracies gives normal results. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to post your code, without code no one would be able to help.

Comment: done, do I also need to post the data?

Comment: Yes, it would help.